# How to replace dbms_obfuscation_toolkit with dbms_crypto

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

After being deprecated for quite some time, Oracle now removed the dbms_obfuscation_toolkit in 21c.
What are the direct replacements for the following functions?

- dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt
- dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESDecrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use one of the `DBMS_CRYPT.ENCRYPT` functions or procedures (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_CRYPTO.html#GUID-CE3CF17D-E781-47CB-AEE7-19A9B2BCD3EC)) with an `encryption_type` of `DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_DES`, plus whatever block cipher suites and modifiers you need.

Example:

```
DECLARE
   input_string       VARCHAR2 (200) :=  'Secret Message';
   output_string      VARCHAR2 (200);
   encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores encrypted binary text
   decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores decrypted binary text
   num_key_bytes      NUMBER := 256/8;        -- key length 256 bits (32 bytes)
   key_bytes_raw      RAW (32);               -- stores 256-bit encryption key
   encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type

                                 DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_DES
                                 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                                 + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_NONE;

   iv_raw             RAW (16);

BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Original string: ' || input_string);
   key_bytes_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES (num_key_bytes);
   iv_raw        := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES (16);
   encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
      (
         src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (input_string,  'AL32UTF8'),
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => key_bytes_raw,
         iv  => iv_raw
      );

    -- The encrypted value "encrypted_raw" can be used here

    decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
      (
         src => encrypted_raw,
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => key_bytes_raw,
         iv  => iv_raw
      );

   output_string := UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (decrypted_raw, 'AL32UTF8');

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Decrypted string: ' || output_string); 
END;
```